# UNIX domain sockets not accessable across users?

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm running a client/server application on Red Hat Enterprise using ZMQ for message passing. The IPC socket used to associate a client with the server is implemented using a Unix domain socket.

If user A starts the server process, it seems like only clients started by user A can connect to and communicate over that socket. Our project requires that the clients be able to be run by different users, so this is a major sticking point.

The socket is located at /tmp/ipc_assoc with default 755 permissions. `chmod` 777 does not fix the problem. `chown` userB allows user B to access the socket, but user A then loses access. Not even root can access the socket. There is no ACL or SeLinux in use on the machine.

Is this typical behavior for Unix domain sockets? Has anyone figured out how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some assistance from the ZMQ mailing list, I have made a work around. It's ugly, but seems to work consistently.

I had to make a subdirectory under /tmp and `chmod 777` it. The server now creates the socket in that new folder. It also programmatically `chmod 777` the socket. Now, as long as the server is run as root, any user can run a client and talk to the server.

I don't know why UNIX domain socket behave this way, but it sure is annoying.

Comment: why does 777 work while 770 doesn't? I'm puzzled, I've put both users under the same group and no go...

Comment: this leaves you open to an attack where an unpriviledged user can create a socket of the same name and receive all the data intended for you. better make the directory not have write permissions, and find a different way of making the socket 777

Answer (score 4):

**chmod(s.sun_path, 0777);** after listening to the socket.

```
domain = AF_UNIX;
name = servname;
port = -1;

n = MakeLocalSocket(s);
if (n == 0) {
    fatal("can't create socket");
}

unlink(s.sun_path);

if (bind(fd, & s, n) < 0) {
    fatal("can't bind socket");
}

if (listen(fd, 5) != 0) {
    fatal("can't listen to socket");
}

/* UNIX domain sockets need to be mode 777 on 4.3 */
chmod(s.sun_path, 0777);
```

Comment: why does 777 work while 770 doesn't? I'm puzzled, I've put both users under the same group and no go...

Comment: Not sure. However, according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html "POSIX does not make any statement about the effect of the permissions on a socket file, and on some systems (e.g., older BSDs), the socket permissions are ignored.  Portable programs should not rely on this feature for security."

Comment: actually, I solved the problem: the user that I added to the group had to re-login for that change to take effect! but thanks for your comment

Comment: (OffTopic NB: love your profile pic, that's from my favorite movie :D )

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily alter the umask:

```
mode_t umask_ = umask(0000); /* let the socket be mode 0777 so that other users can connect */
int err = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&unix_bind_addr, sizeof(unix_bind_addr));
umask(umask_); /* restore old umask (0777 is a pretty bad choice for normal stuff) */
if (err) {
  /* handle bind error here */
}
```

Of course, this is a bad idea if you're using threads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding UserA and UserB into a common user group?

Comment: Is is a symbolic link to another file with different permissions?

Comment: No, if you run `ls -l` on the socket, it prints out "srwxr-xr-x ... ipc_assoc"

Comment: Well, this seems to show that the socket is only r/w/x for the owner, not the group. When you create the file in the server process, it will use the umask for the process 755, programatically change either the mask, or chmod the file to 770.