# ZeroMQ and PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, zeromq

I just came across the problem that ZeroMQ in PHP seems to work properly when used on the command line, but not in an FPM process. Did anyone else observe this behaviour? Is there an easy solution? Maybe it is a matter of rights management or something? Unfortunately there are no error messages at all.

---

The server is started from the command line:

```
$context = new ZMQContext;
$socket = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$socket->bind('ipc:///tmp/test.sock');
while (true) echo $socket->recv();
```

Another script is located on my local webserver (nginx + php-fpm):

```
$context = new ZMQContext;
$socket = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$socket->connect('ipc:///tmp/test.sock');
$socket->send('Test Message');
```

If one executes this script from the command line, the message is transferred to the zmq server without problems. If I execute the script through the browser, nothing happens.

Comment: What are the permissions of the file `/tmp/test.sock` ?

Comment: Already set to 0777...

Comment: Update: Just tried to use TCP now and it works. However, would be interesting to know what the IPC problem is about.

Comment: I have the issue only when the socket file is not writable by the apache user, a `700` owned by `apache` works. Do you have something that could block it ? selinux for example ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, although I'm using an IP address instead of a .sock file. Did you do anything specifically that helped it to work in a browser? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the zeromq bug tickets, this is a known problem, but they have no intention of fixing it:

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/48

I also tried changing permissions, as indicated on other threads (and confirmed that I am successfully creating them as 0777 when viewed in the filesystem), but no luck with zeromq:

[UNIX domain sockets not accessable across users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457944/unix-domain-sockets-not-accessable-across-users)

I also finally gave up and used TCP.